# How can I debug clazy-standalone run from xargs?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've built `clazy-standalone` and I'm running it on my codebase but it keeps crashing so I want to debug it in Visual Studio Code. Unfortunately the command line to run it is:

```
find . -name "*cpp" | xargs /usr/bin/clazy-standalone (other params)
```

Is it possible to put this into `launch.json`? Alternatively, can I get Visual Studio Code to connect to the process when it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Visual Studio, but if you isolate the culprit and make a test-case I'm happy to debug and fix it in clazy

Comment: That's part of the problem - it's an intermittent crash so the only test case is to run it on my codebase. But I'm making progress!